# Node/NPM works, but globally installed packages not recognized in MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, node-modules

I got a Apple Macbook Air which is my first Mac OS device. I installed NPM and immediately got errors since I did not have permission for root. Searched online and the most upvoted "fixes", but not a single one of them worked, but eventually moved the PATH which I think caused some issues and want to fix it/resolve them.

In terminal if I do:

```
node -v
```

It works.

I can also install npm packages:

```
npm i -g yo
```

My problem is that I cannot use/consume any of the installed npm packages as they are not recognized. As above command, I would expect this to work.
yo

But it does not. "command not found: yo"

My path:

```
echo $PATH

/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/USERNAME/homebrew/bin
```

In nano .zshrc i have:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/USERNAME/homebrew/bin
```

Any clue how to solve it? Or in worst case, reset to default?